# vscode exits with this message C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, system32

from past few days vscode terminal not working and giving this error and also powershell not starting.

tried sfc /scannow and various other methdods from yt and sites.
but still not working
is there some solution available for this??

Comment: The filename you posted is where the PS executable is locating in Windows.  I suspect the executable is already running.  You may of shutdown windows will the program is executing and when you restarted the machine windows automatically started the program again.  Open up Task Manager and look for all processes powershell.exe and kill these processes.  Then try again.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i have tried that also.
What really worked for me was that i installed a newer version of powershell and changed the vscode settings to point to that version although powershell not working but there isnt any problem in vscode now.

Comment: What is not working in PS?  It sound like the environmental variable PSModulePath is not set properly.  You may of done an installation and didn't specify all users so the environment was modified for one user and not all users.  Press Start and then type : Edit Environment Variables for you account.  Check PSModulePath for both user and system.